# Vector representation of a sum

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, summation

I am trying to solve a minimization problem and I encountered the following sum:

$\sum_i^n x_i^4$

I know that $\sum_i^n x_i^2 = x'x$ but I can't figure out what the vector representation is of the first sum.

I hope someone could help me.

Comment: Why would you like to solve this using vector representations? And what are the constraints on the $x_i$ (is their sum or product constant, or something else?)

Comment: The constraint is $\sum_{i = 0}^n x_i^4 \leq 1$ @Ragnar

Comment: And what would you like to achieve? A maximal sum of the $x_i$?

Comment: The inequality of the quadratic mean and normal mean may help. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean